# Appending HTML to paragraph tag inside a div with multiple class labels.

Tags: jquery, dom

I have the following HTML (I am working with an existing HTML document that I can't easily change, hence the structure):

```
<div class="one-third last">
<p>
</p>
</div>
```

Which I want to apply the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("one-third last p").append("Hello Everybody!");
});
```

Obviously the **'one-third last p'** doesn't work, but I'd like to know what I'd have to use to target it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the '.' - to get element's by classname.

Use ".firstclass.anotherclass element" or "sometagorclass:last :first"....etc.

```
$(".one-third:last p").append('Hello Everybody!');
```

or

```
$(".one-third.last p").append('Hello Everybody!');
```

Answer (score 2):

use `.` for classes everywhere without giving space, You are missing `.`

```
 $("one-third.last p").append("Hello Everybody!");
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$(".one-third.last p").append("Hello Everybody!");
```

Class names are written as [dot]+class name.

Classes on same element are written without space.

[More information here.](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set points for class selectors:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".one-third.last p").append("Hello Everybody!");
});
```